# Install application without developer certificate?

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak

I am willing to jailbreak my device, but not sure what to do after that.

Dev program application will take too long for a demo I hope to do on hardware tomorrow.

EDITED: It doesn't need to be 4.1 on an iPhone 4

Comment: dev program application used to take a couple of hours, has it gotten worse?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot jailbreak an iPhone 4 on 4.1 sorry! That makes this impossible as far as I know. Sorry!

My recommendation would be to find someone with a developer certificate who could help you out.

If you can find a jail broken device the guys answer below me talks about how to do it with openssh.

Comment: Ok, I can also jailbreak my touch.

Answer (score 1):

Once you've jailbroken your phone, you can harness the power of OpenSSH and [this code "signing" guide from Saurik](http://www.saurik.com/id/8) and pseudo-sign your app, allowing it to run on the device.